# WildFly error serving files (unable to find or serve resource from library)

Tags: java, windows-10, wildfly, wildfly-9

I'm maintaining a Java web application, it's running on wildFly 9.0.2.

Since about a month I noticed some new warning messages in the console while running the application locally. It wasn't happening in our production environments even after a deploy, so I thought it was a local problem, like antivirus, but yesterday the same error message appeared in production environment.

It does not stops the pages from working, it not even seems to slow down the service. But it pollutes a lot the logs.

Here's the message:

```
10:59:16,361 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-31) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, theme.css, from library, primefaces-tce.
10:59:16,361 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-31) : java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.write(NioSocketConduit.java:161)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:621)
    at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.doWrite(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:163)
    at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.write(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:127)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:150)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.write(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:240)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.write(HttpServerExchange.java:1903)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:567)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:220)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:358)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:153)
    at org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:87)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:655)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at br.ufpi.tce.sagresWeb.filter.PaginasFilter.doFilter(PaginasFilter.java:94)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The same message appears also related to jquery.js and other libs. Always the same message, changing only the resource name and the library.

I've tried disabling my antivirus (kaspersky endpoint), I have no local firewall, the network admin even disabled the corporate firewall for my PC (but the problem does not seem to be external), with no luck. The behavior didn't change.

How can I find out what's going on?